# How do I create a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point?

Tags: c#, methods, static-methods

I have recently begun starting on methods in C#, and I keep getting the error "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point". I have tried changing some of the static void methods to Main but it does not work. I have also attempted to add a static void Main() but it does not work either.

```
using System;

namespace L07_Req1_FunMethods
{
    public class Conversions

    {
  static void Write()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the number of degrees Farenheit you would like to convert to Celcius: ");
        }
        static int far = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        static double cel = .555555555 * (far - 32);
        static void fToC()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} degrees Farenheit is equal to {1} degrees Celcius.", far, cel);

            Console.Write("Now enter the number of Celcius you would like to convert to Farenheit: ");
        }
        static int cel2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        static double far2 = (cel2 + 32) / .5555555555;
        static void cToF()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} degrees Celcius is equal to {1} degrees Farenheit.", cel2, far2);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
    }
```

This is my code with where I attempted to add a static void Main()
using System;

```
namespace L07_Req1_FunMethods
{
    public class Conversions

    {
static void Main()
{

}
  static void Write()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the number of degrees Farenheit you would like to convert to Celcius: ");
        }
        static int far = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        static double cel = .555555555 * (far - 32);
        static void fToC()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} degrees Farenheit is equal to {1} degrees Celcius.", far, cel);

            Console.Write("Now enter the number of Celcius you would like to convert to Farenheit: ");
        }
        static int cel2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        static double far2 = (cel2 + 32) / .5555555555;
        static void cToF()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} degrees Celcius is equal to {1} degrees Farenheit.", cel2, far2);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: You say that you attempted to add a static void Main. But I don't see that in the code in your question. What was wrong with that attempt?

Comment: I attempted to add it right above static void Write(), but it kept giving the error.

Comment: Show that in your question, and provide the error that you got when you did so.

Comment: You have a class project and not a console application.  For an application to run from windows you need a entry point and a class application does not have an entry point.

Comment: To that end, you can create a console application in the same solution that calls your methods as part of the Main method that it will automatically generate for you. Its not enough to have a method named `Main`, you could have 50 methods named `Main` scattered throughout the code. It needs to know which one is the `entry point`. In your project settings this is referred to as the `startup object`. It will look for Main there. But class libraries do not have Main methods, they are made to be consumed into other applications that do have an entry method. They aren't to be run by themselves.

Comment: Which project is set as your startup project (Right click your solution, click properties, then drill down to Common Properties > Startup Project)? What project type is that project (Right click on the project, click Properties, make sure you're on the Application tab, and look at the Output Type)?

Answer (score 4):

When a console application starts, the OS calls the `Main()` method. That's why it's complaining that it doesn't exist. That is called the "entry point". It is how the OS starts running your code.

What you have is a bunch of methods and [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) of a class, but no way for anything to start running your code.

I'm pretty sure you want all that code in your `Main` method, like this:

```
namespace L07_Req1_FunMethods
{
    public class Conversions
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the number of degrees Farenheit you would like to convert to Celcius: ");
            int far = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            double cel = .555555555 * (far - 32);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} degrees Farenheit is equal to {1} degrees Celcius.", far, cel);

            Console.Write("Now enter the number of Celcius you would like to convert to Farenheit: ");
            int cel2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            double far2 = (cel2 + 32) / .5555555555;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} degrees Celcius is equal to {1} degrees Farenheit.", cel2, far2);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Main` method can have different signatures. A [method signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#method-signatures) refers to the combination of return type and the parameters. For example, if you want to pass parameters into your program from the command line, you can create your `Main` method like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

And all the parameters from the command line will be in the `args` array.

There is more detail on the `Main` method here: [Main() and command-line arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/). You will see on the left of that article that it is just one in a series of articles. You can continue reading to learn more about how console applications work.